# Pass variable in every view file - laravel

Tags: laravel, controller

I want to send some variable in every views which contains data from database. I have written the following code in base controller because it is extended by all of the controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $opening_hours = OpeningHours::first();
    $social_media = SocialMedia::first();
    $website = Website::first();

    view()->share('opening_hours', $opening_hours)
        ->share('social_media', $social_media)
        ->share('website', $website);
}
```

Also I have also called `parent::__construct();` in all of my controllers. But, I am still getting undefined variable `$opening_hours` in view file when I try to debug it. How can I send website data (website logo, contact, email) that has to be included in every views file?

Comment: `view()->share(...)` returns the second argument, not the view factory itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel provides us some features like this. You can try View Composers. These are very useful if we want some data on every screen. But we want to place this on separate place instead of writing code in every controller.

```
https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers
```

That will help us.

Answer (score 0):

You are a file called `AppServiceProvider.php` inside of `app/Providers` folder, In there you can do the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use View;
use App\OpeningHours;
use App\SocialMedia;
use App\Website;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        $contact_details = [
            'opening_hours' => OpeningHours::first(),
            'social_media' = SocialMedia::first(),
            'website' => Website::first(),
        ];

        View::share('contact_details', $contact_details);
    }
}
```

Updated and added a guess to the namespace of the models being used.

Comment: It says Class `'App\Providers\OpeningHours'` not found

Comment: @Alisha This is because you will need to use it at the top of the file or use the PSR4 namespace. e.g. `use App\OpeningHours;` under `use View;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way
Create a one middleware and add this code into middleware and use middle where you want this data and data will be available on that view.

```
$opening_hours = OpeningHours::first();
$social_media = SocialMedia::first();
$website = Website::first();

view()->share('opening_hours', $opening_hours)
    ->share('social_media', $social_media)
    ->share('website', $website);
```